# What are "vocabulary types", and how many exist?

Tags: types, functional-programming, programming-languages, category-theory, type-theory

Across programming languages, I've encountered similar [composite types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_data_type) with different names:

1. [Optional / Maybe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Option_type)
2. [Any](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/any)
3. [Variant / Sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union)
4. [Record / Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_type)

People often use the term **vocabulary type**,
yet I've never seen a definition of what makes a type "vocabulary".

Does this term have a loose definition?
What does type theory and other programming languages have to say about vocabulary types?

Is everything above a vocabulary type?  Are there more?

Comment: Can you give any links/citations for the term “vocabulary type” used in context? I’ve never seen it before and I’m curious if it would help provide more background for an answer. These are mostly [algebraic data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type).

Comment: As Jon said, where have you seen vocabulary type used in relation to these terms?  Not something I've come across, even after doing a internet search for it

Comment: show us the reference but i think it means there are different type of vocabularies to refer to a particular type !

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/213114/joaqu%C3%ADn-m-l%C3%B3pez-mu%C3%B1oz has stuff to tell you about then. Check out his pdf about them https://github.com/joaquintides/usingstdcpp2017

Answer (score 3):

My understanding of vocabulary with respect to programming and vocabulary type in general is something that gives to certain objects properties with well defined meaning.

Here are some examples in Haskell:

Consider `Optional` / `Maybe` type and a pure function that takes HTTP reply of a web server and extracts reply's code.

```
getCode :: String -> Int
```

Now suppose by the time we run this function we don't know if response was successful or not - code might not be present at all. How do we represent case when code is missing? We can assign some artificial value `-1` or `0` or we can change whole function type to this:

```
getCode :: String -> Maybe Int
```

In addition `Maybe` forms a `Monad`, `Functor`, `Applicative`, `Foldable` and a bunch of other typeclasses in Haskell. Each typeclass adds extra abilities to manipulate value in question while respecting it's presence/absence.

`Product` / `Sum` type in Haskell are represented as pairs and `Either a b`. Again - defining something via `Product` or `Sum` adds a well defined meaning `Product a b` - both values must be present, `Sum a b` - one value must be present and adds a bunch of laws for free.

Comment: I think this answer is missing slightly the question, which is `what makes a type "vocabulary"?` as opposed to `what do these types do?`.

Comment: `Well defined meaning is`. For those familiar with math/programming terminology "This operation in commutative and associative" tells about as much about operation as "Type of `Thing` is `Maybe Stuff`".

Answer (score 0):

The types that are commonly used in a code-base define its vocabulary. As an example, a code-base may need an agreed upon way to convey:

- Time points
- Strings
- Loggers
- Integers

While many implementations exist, even in simple C-like scalar types like `int64_t, int32_t, int, long, long long`, we call **vocabulary types** the types that are most commonly passed through interfaces.

Depending on the domain and language, vocabulary types emerge across code-bases as a commonly accepted industry standard. An example of that is the use of `cv::Mat` to represent images in code implementing computer vision functionality.

But generally the lines are somewhat blurred when it comes to calling a type "vocabulary". A good rule of thumb is that if undergoing the transition from using e.g. `Logger` to `Logger2` would a substantial engineering effort touching much of the code-base, **then the logger type can be considered a vocabulary type**.

The term **vocabulary type** pops up when:

- expressing costs in architecture and refactoring
- summarizing designs and requirements
- evaluating impact of third-party components

A **case study on vocabulary types** (in the context of the Google code-base) can be found here: [The ecosystem expense of vocabulary types](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p2125r0.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to base this answer on the [open-std pdf by Titus Winters](https://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2020/p2125r0.pdf).

> what we
> call “vocabulary types” - these are the most common generic forms of data for any project.
> These tend to be basic forms of data: strings, integers, arrays/vectors, timestamps and
> durations, perhaps a hashmap

> There is **no clear delineation for what is and is not a “vocabulary” type**: clearly this is shades of
> gray. Anecdotal analysis suggests that the distribution of type references within a codebase
> follows a Zipfian distribution, akin to the distribution of word occurrence in language. Some
> types don’t pass through interfaces much at all. Some types aren’t used much. Other types are
> used everywhere and pass through interfaces constantly. Modifying those types directly (while
> obeying existing invariants) is highly valuable. Changing the set of those types must be handled
> with care.

So in my understanding, `optional`, `any`, `variant`, are not special vocabulary types, they may not even be in the vocab of certain projects.
It seems to me, some programmers did attribute a different meaning when they mention "C++ vocabulary types", they probably mean "*semantic decorators*" with shared convention among the C++ community. Like `optional` just wraps a type T but tells you something meta about T. And that meta-something is of nature known by all C++ programmers, it thus "speaks" to them, and by that, it's part of the vocabulary.
I don't think that's the right definition, T.Winters's one makes more sense.